# SmartStore.net .net framework version SQL Server Express edition

Tags: .net, version, nopcommerce, sql-server-2014-express

I am investigating smartstore.net for a client.
http://www.smartstore.com/net/en/

From reading the system requirements it states that you have to have .net 4.5 but can have SQL Server 2008 Express.

https://github.com/smartstoreag/SmartStoreNET/wiki/system-requirements

When I go to run against SQL Server 2014 Express I see that it says it can only be used with .net4

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=42299

So my question is, is this indeed true.. SQL Server 2014 can only use .net 4, which is a bit of a limitation as I wanted to use VS 2015 Community (which has .net 4.6)

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 2):

I believe that ".Net 4 only" refers to the **SQL-CLR**, the built-in CLR runtime **inside** of SQL Server.

But SQL Server 2014 Express as a whole very happily runs on my .NET 4.5.2 equipped machines - absolutely **no problems** in that regard

Comment: hmm interesting so.. I will install so and see can I get working with 4.5.2 so.. appreciate your prompt reply :)